# How to load seperate debug file e.g. abc.debug file instead of binary to debug in GDB?

Tags: linux, coredump, debug-symbols, postmortem-debugging

"gdb program core.11230"

is the actual format of loading core to gdb. But I don't have 'program' binary. instead I have separate debug file along with core. So I am loading .debug file instead of binary as

"gdb coredump.debug coredump_core.dump"

```
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /root/coredump.debug...done.


warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffdf0f23000
Core was generated by `./coredump'.

Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000400848 in main ()

Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.12-1.212.0.1.el6.x86_64 libgcc-4.4.7-23.0.1.el6.x86_64
(gdb)
(gdb) list +
1       coredump.cpp: No such file or directory.
        in coredump.cpp
(gdb) bt
```

It won't show me the exact line number and source code file while debugging in GDB. It is not the case with normal debugging with binary and core.

also I don't have source file. I have access only to core dump and separate debug files.

What am I doing wrong. Please some experts suggest?

Comment: @Employed Russian I could not add comment to existing question "How to load text (not binary) debugging informaton from a seperate file with GDB?". so asking new question.